# Why my Discord bot always sends duplicated message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As the title says, when my Discord bot tries to send messages, it always sends the message **twice**!
I know where the problem is in the code, but I don't know how to fix it.

Code about sending messages:

```py
    for i in range(len(final_msg_list)):
        new_log = str(message.channel) + "/" + str(client.user) + ":\n" + str(final_msg_list[i-1]) + "\n\n"
        log_writter.write_log(new_log)
        if isinstance(final_msg_list[i], discord.File):
            await message.channel.send(file=final_msg_list[i])
        elif isinstance(final_msg_list[i], discord.Embed):
            await message.channel.send(embed=final_msg_list[i])
        elif isinstance(final_msg_list[i], str):
            await message.channel.send(final_msg_list[i])
```

The bot's log:

```py
[2022-04-15 PM 12:11:42]Channel/me#5877:
y!test

[2022-04-15 PM 12:11:42]Channel/Bot#0359:
test

[2022-04-15 PM 12:11:42]Channel/Bot#0359:
test
```

And sorry for my bad English...

**UPDATE**: I found a way to solve that problem!

```
    for i in range(len(final_msg_list)):
        current_msg = final_msg_list[i]
        if isinstance(current_msg, discord.File):
            await message.channel.send(file=final_msg_list[i])
        elif isinstance(current_msg, discord.Embed):
            await message.channel.send(embed=final_msg_list[i])
        elif isinstance(current_msg, str):
            await message.channel.send(final_msg_list[i])
```

I set a new variable: `current_msg = final_msg_list[i]`, and change every `final_msg_list[i]` into `current_msg`, and that works!
But I still don't know how this work...?

Comment: It seems like this is an `on_message` event. Can you send all of your code there?

Comment: https://github.com/Alllen95Wei/YuriBot/commit/796b00658c890bd2bbd3fc7f7c108e790b3fadc9

Comment: Try adding `if message.author.id == client.user.id: return` to the top of `on_message`.

Comment: I found a way to solve that!
https://github.com/Alllen95Wei/YuriBot/commit/b648e62baa4b11404075336e38328162c9004f84